# (SQL) integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, sql-insert

I did look up for solutions for this problem but i still get the same error..

I'm trying to insert values into PART and MANUFACTURER tables. Initially, i inserted values into MANUFACTURER without knowing the fact i need to deal with the parent table i.e. PART. So, i did the PART then the MANUFACTURER but still not working :(.

These are the tables:

```
PART(PNum, PName, PUnitPrice, ComponentOf)
primary key (PNum)
foreign key (ComponentOf) references PART(PNum)

MANUFACTURER(MName, MAddress, MPhone)
primary key (MName)
candidate key (MPhone)
candidate key (MAddress)

PART-MANUFACTURED(MDate, PNum, MName, Quantity)
primary key (MName, PNum, MDate)
foreign key (PNum) references PART(PNum)
foreign key (MName) references MANUFACTURER(MName)

CUSTOMER(CNum, CName, CType)
primary key (CNum)
domain constraint ctype in ('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUTION')

ORDERS(CNum, PNum, OrderDate, OrderQuantity)
primary key (CNum, PNum, OrderDate)
foreign key (CNum) references CUSTOMER(CNum)
foreign key (PNum) references PART(PNum)
```

Create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE PART(PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, PName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL, PUnitPrice NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL, ComponentOf VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(PNum), FOREIGN KEY(ComponentOf) REFERENCES PART(PNum));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER(MName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, MAddress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, MPhone VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(MName), CONSTRAINT UK_MADDRESS Unique(MAddress), CONSTRAINT UK_MPHONE UNIQUE(MPhone));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE PARTMANUFACTURED(MDate DATE NOT NULL, PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, MName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, QUANTITY NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(MName, PNum, MDate), FOREIGN KEY(PNum) REFERENCES PART(PNum), FOREIGN KEY(MName) REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(MName));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(CNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, CName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL, CType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(CNum), CHECK(Ctype in('INDIVIDUAL','INSTITUTION')));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE ORDERS(CNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, OrderDate DATE NOT NULL, OrderQuantity NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(CNum, PNum, OrderDate), FOREIGN KEY(CNum) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CNum), FOREIGN KEY(PNum) REFERENCES PART(PNum));
```

Isn't the PNum already the primary or parent key? and PART table is the parent table? since, other tables have the PNum as foreign key.. i really don't get it..

anyone knows and can help me with it, is greatly appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: What is the insert statement that is giving you an error?

Comment: @JRD `INSERT INTO PART VALUES('S001', 'System-economy', 1100, 'Null');`

Comment: Why did you make ComponentOf a foreign key?

Comment: @BasDeBeer ermm... it is stated in my assignment given by my lecturer..>.<

Comment: `'Null'` is the string literal. Remove the single quotes to insert `null` value.

Comment: hey it works :o thanks!. but how is it that the null able to erm how to say it.. like.. to remove the error.. thought it was something to do with the parent/primary key thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with your insert statement `INSERT INTO PART VALUES('S001', 'System-economy', 1100, 'Null')` is that you are trying to insert a string `'NULL'` rather than an actual `NULL` for the column `ComponentOf` in the `PART` table.

The problem with the string `'NULL'` is that you have a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on `ComponentOf` that references the column `PNum`, which means that all the values in the column `ComponentOf` must also be in `PNum`. However, there is no value `'NULL'` in `PNum` so that's why it threw the error. An actual `NULL` works since it means that it is not referencing anything.

Answer (score 1):

The value inserted for `ComponentOf` has to match an existing `PNum` in the `PARTS` table.  Your key is their to ensure you don't have any "orphaned" components.

If you try to insert `'Null'` (a string value as mentioned in the comments) then it can't find the "parent".  However, `null` is allowed since it means that particular part is not a component of any other part, i.e. it doesn't have a "parent".